# Finding and replacing specified character in java

Tags: java

How to replace the character at specified index?

I tried below way ,but string length will vary, so my code is failing.

```
StringBuilder s =new StringBuilder("{1:Gxxxxxxxxxxx000000000Y}{2:YYYYYYY}");

s.setCharAt(pos+24, '1');
```

result : {1:Gxxxxxxxxxxx0000000001}{2:YYYYYYY} (Correct result)

But above code failed with below string ,Its not giving exception .it is giving inccorect result. :

```
StringBuilder s =new StringBuilder("{1:GxxxxxxxxxxxYYY000000000Y}{2:YYYYYYY}");
```

result : {1:GxxxxxxxxxxxYYY000000100Y}{2:YYYYYYY} (incorrect)

expected:{1:GxxxxxxxxxxxYYY0000000001}{2:YYYYYYY}

I know if i use `pos+27` it works , but i need a proper way to do it ,because string may vary.

Regards,

Chaitu

Comment: You say `code failed`, not in the sense that it gave an exception, but that it didn't give you the desired result, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what is the correct description of the point where you want put your `'1'`.

If, for instance, you want to set the character immediately before the first `'}'` to `'1'` you can use `indexOf()` to find the position of the first `'}'` and then subtract one from it to get the position just before it:

```
s.setCharAt(s.indexOf('}') - 1, '1');
```

EDIT

Assuming you want to find the first `}` that comes after the first `{1:`, here's I'd go about it:

(a) You first need to find the starting point, which, in your case, is `indexOf("{1:")`

(b) You then need find the first `}` the comes after that. For this you can use another variant of `indexOf()` which takes as a parameter the index to start from. In other words we take the index from (a) and use it as the starting point:  `s.indexOf("}", s.indexOf("{1:"))`

This boils down to:

```
s.setCharAt(s.indexOf("}", s.indexOf("{1:")) - 1, '1');
```

Comment: For safety : I want to find both {1: and "}"

Comment: please take another look.

Answer (score 0):

Are you always replacing the same part of the string, even though the length may vary?  i.e. if it's always the bit at the end of `1{...Y}` then use something like `s.indexOf( "Y}" )` to give you the character position you need to replace.  Obviously this assumes there are no other instances of that string before the one you want.

Comment: No, it may chnage .instead of Y i may get Z

Comment: Then you just need two 'rules', one to handle the case of `Y}` and another for `Z}`, the code to replace both would be the same.